# How can I add a Road Side Unit into a NS-2 and Sumo Simulation

Tags: ns2, sumo, 802.11p

I have an 802.11p NS-2 simulation with some nodes that use SUMO trajectories, Right now I'm testing the V2V (vehicle to vehicle) communication measuring the throughout with DSDV and AODV routing protocols but I also need to test the V2I (vehicle to infrastructure) communication and I don't know how to add a RSU(Road Side Unit) into my scenario. Does someone have the a code to be able to implement the RSU into my simulation?

Comment: Google, ns2 add a RSU(Road Side Unit) https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+add+a+RSU(Road+Side+Unit) .... 1´ hit : »» just add static nodes as RSUs «« https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_implement_RSU_Road_Side_Unit_infrastructure_communication_in_Vehicular_networks_VANETs_using_ns-3

Comment: That link you provide is for NS3 not NS2

Comment: The headline is ns3. Please read the text about ns2 https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_implement_RSU_Road_Side_Unit_infrastructure_communication_in_Vehicular_networks_VANETs_using_ns-3 .... : » @Johan Ericka : in my research, i just add static nodes as RSUs . ... 
nb: **i use NS2** ««

Comment: So I just need to add a static node to my simulation? Is there a way to add it in a certain point of my scenario? my sumo scenario is based on osm.

Comment: Static : Set a node position. And do not include the node in the movement scenario.

Comment: Ok I think I have an idea of what you're saying, I have tested that and I see a static node in my simulation the thing is that I don't know how to put those static nodes in one particulate place of my scenario and also how to give the node different parameters to make it look like a realistic Road side unit